# Simplest way to use ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I have been trying to write a simple angular.js app, that includes another file using ng-include. I must have done something/missed something so that the included file does not  get included. I must be doing something fundamentally wrong but can't see what it is.

Here is Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head ng-app="app">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0" data-semver="1.2.0"     src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-resource@1.2.0" data-semver="1.2.0" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="appctrl">
        <h1>Airports</h1>
        <div ng-include="'extra.html'"></div>
        <h1>Airports</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

file extra.html contains the element to be included

```
<h2>Inside</h2>
```

and script.js is the file to initialise angular

```
(function () { 
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.run(['$route',  function ($route) {  // Include $route to kick start the router.
    }]);        

    angular.module('app').controller('appctrl', [function AppCtrl() { }]);
});
```

I created to [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qmSNxwnqCuIgEpT4e8BB?p=preview%20Plunk) to demonstrate what I mean. There's not much there: the ng-app defined, references to the angular files and a couple of titles to delineate the insert point. Nothing is shown between.

What is the simplest way to use ng-include in angular.js?

Comment: You are missing angular-route.js

Answer (score 3):

1. Place `ng-app` on your body section.
2. Include `angular-route.js` (eg. `<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular-route.js"></script>`) and add this dependency to your app initialization (`var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute']`)
3. Don't put your script.js code inside `(function(){})`. (If you want to do this, call this function `(function(){})();`)

Your code with changes: http://plnkr.co/edit/k1dFPeb9E2B2pjTthi1K?p=preview

Comment: That is brilliant. I'm very appreciative. I tried it without  steps 1 and 2 and with step 3 in place, the include still worked. I think I'll follow the steps as good form anyway. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a script of mine:

HTML:

```
<div id="superhero-nav-container">
    <ul id="superhero-nav">
        <li><a ng-click='template = templates[0]'>Biography & Stats</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click='template = templates[1]'>History</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click='template = templates[2]'>Powers</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click='template = templates[3]'>Enemies</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="superhero-templates" ng-include src='template.url'></div>
```

JS in the controller:

```
    $scope.templates = [
        { url: '/views/superheroes/biography.html' },
        { url: '/views/superheroes/history.html' },
        { url: '/views/superheroes/powers.html' },
        { url: '/views/superheroes/enemies.html' }
    ];
    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
```

I have something like menu that changes the html in the bottom div. Hope that helps.

**EDIT (for the comment below):**

Your mistakes were:

1. Put your `ng-app` attribute in the html tag of the
   document not in the head
2. Include angular-resource.js (eg. `<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular-resource.js"></script>`) and add this dependency to your app initialization:

   angular.module('app', ['ngResource']) ...
3. Don't put your script.js code inside (`function(){}`). If you want to do this, call this

   `function (function(){})();`

**Here is your working code:** [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fETpisDaan97mXQ6DqcF?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I tried adding your code into my sample but the effect was the same. When I looked at the debugger, however, I noticed an "uncaught object" error deep in Angular. There is something else going on that stops the file being loaded. I haven't found it yet. Here's a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XeP6dGxZl2GGn2hF81qC?p=preview) with the added changes.